# How to handle special characters in android espresso framework?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I've a textview having value "What’s Next?". When I am identifying the object using android device monitor, it shows me the text value as "What?s Next?".  ie all special characters are replaced with '?' in android device monitor while trying to identify and capture object properties.

I am writing espresso tests and would like to use text property alongwith the object id to uniquely identify the object. But don't know how to handle the special characters as mentioned above.
Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't object id always be unique?